# Cognos Connection - No cognos mobile portal

Tags: mobile, connection, portal, cognos

I recently installed Cognos BI Server 10.1.1 or my computer. It seems work propertly because I can access to cognos connection with this URL hostname:9300/p2pd/servlet/dispatch with a copy of installation_c10/webcontent to installation_c10/webapps/p2pd

So I used only tomcat and no webserver to access cognos via the dispacther. I prefer keep this configuration.

Then I also installed Cognos Mobile (the same version 10.1.1) but when I go to cognos connection I have no choice between desktop or mobile portal and I don't no why.

It is possible with the dispacther to go to the mobile portal ?

Answer (score 0):

The mobile portal isn't offered as a choice, it's simply a separate URL.
If you added Cognos mobile after the initial installation you will need to ensure you copy the webcontent over to webapps/p2pd again.  Once that is done you should be able to access the mobile portal at: hostname:9300/p2pd/servlet/dispatch/m